# Bound fields/alternative input modes

Tags: programming, alternatives

My UI allows users to specify values that may be "bound" to other values. In the simple case, I want to present friendly input elements like checkboxes and password boxes. But I also need a way to allow advanced users to "bind" the value to another value (much like the way Expression Blend allows you to enter values, or bind them).

Here's what I have so far. Here we have two checkboxes:

[image: Example with two checkboxes]

But when the user clicks the little square on the right-hand side, they can enter a raw value or bind it using an expression:

[image: Example with bound values]

[See the JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulstovell/SYHgU/12/embedded/result/)

Are there better ways the 'binding toggle' buttons could be displayed that would make it more user friendly, keeping in mind that there might be dozens of these inputs on a single page?

Are there any other examples of this on the web that I can look at for inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

The current design is very confusing. One solution could be more like old school:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Yh8K.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>